# java record compact constructor bytecode

Tags: java, record, bytecode, java-17

I was transforming a simple class to a record, which looks like this:

```
public class Mine {
    private final String name;
    public Mine(String name) {
        this.name = name == null ? "a" : name;
    }
}
```

Instinctively, I wrote it like this:

```
public record Mine(String name) {
    public Mine {
        this.name = name == null ? "a" : name;
    }
}
```

which fails to compile: `cannot assign a value to final variable name`.

I was a little confused, because this compact constructor works:

```
    public Mine {
        name = name == null ? "a" : name;
    }
```

I could not really understand what is going on, so I decided to look at the bytecode:

```
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Record."<init>":()V
         4: aload_1
         5: ifnonnull     13
         8: ldc           #7                  // String a
        10: goto          14
        13: aload_1
        14: astore_1
        15: aload_0
        16: aload_1
        17: putfield      #9                  // Field name:Ljava/lang/String;
        20: return
```

Seems like `javac`, when it sees an assignment to a record variable (`name`) will actually "save" that to a local variable:

```
astore_1
```

and then it does `this.name=<local>`, something like this:

```
public Mine {
   String local = name == null ? "a" : name;
   this.name = local;
}
```

---

If you look at the bytecode of an equivalent class:

```
public class Mine {
    private final String name;

    public Mine(String name) {
        String local = name == null ? "a" : name;
        this.name = local;
    }
}
```

it is almost the same, with the difference that `aload_2` is used instead of `aload_1`, which is not a big deal, and most probably has to do with compatibility reasons.

Can someone confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: You can reassign parameters. Compare the bytecode of a normal class with `name = name == null ? "a" : name; this.name = name;` to a record constructor.

Comment: Your `class Mine` has just a `private final String` but no getter to return it. Isn't your class totally useless?

Comment: Java Language Specification [8.10.4.2. Compact Canonical Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10.4.2-300-C): "*The body must not contain an assignment to a component field of the record class.*" that is, you are allowed to change to the parameters, but not assign to the fields - this is done by the compiler: "*The intent of a compact constructor declaration is that only code to validate or normalize parameters needs to be given in the constructor body; the remaining initialization code is supplied by the compiler.*"

Comment: @JohannesKuhn indeed, now that I know that that is actually a local variable, it makes sense. But think about the case when someone reads a record code : `name = name == null ? "a" : name;`. Without _knowing_ that this is actually a local variable assignment, this code is confusing, at best, right?

Comment: maybe `if (name == null) { name = "a"; }`  is better (not ideal either IMO - I would prefer `this(name==null ? "a" : name)` but that is not allowed in the canonical constructor)

Comment: Its simpler than that.  `this.name` refers to a field; `name` refers to a constructor parameter.  The constructor parameters of a compact constructor are implicitly committed to the fields at the end of the constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- A compact record constructor has implicit parameters corresponding to each record component, matching the declaration of the record.  (You write `public Mine {}`, and it acts like `public Mine(String name) {}`, because your record was defined as `record Mine(String name)`.
- These are *parameters*, when you refer to `name` in your Mine constructor, it refers to that *parameter*. They are not final.
- At the very end of your constructor, all parameters (that is, the value they have at that point; you can change them, given that they aren't final) are written into the fields, which are `final` and cannot be made non-final. It's as if the compiler adds `this.name = name;` for you at the end and just before every `return;`. You can't ask the compiler to skip this step.
- Given that your fields are auto-assigned at the end, and are always `final`, you cannot assign them anywhere in your actual code. After all, if you do that, then you assigned them, and later on the automatically generated `this.name = name`, *also* assigns them, and that's illegal java. Therefore, `this.anyField =` is an instant error in a record constuctor, you can never write this.
- Given that the fields are assigned at the end, reading them before then is invalid, as they haven't been set yet. Therefore, just like the previous bullet said that assigning them (`this.field =`...) is necessarily an error, so is reading them. Conclusion: `this.field` **is wrong** in any record constructor. The compiler knows what you mean when you write it (i.e. syntactically it is valid java; the compiler understands what it means), but will always emit an error when you do so (i.e. it is semantically *invalid*).
- Thus, life's simple: Just use the 'field name' (here, `name`), without `this`, and everything just works. In fact, given that it is a hidden param, you can't even shadow it out: `String name = "haha shadowed out!";` inside your record constructor wouldn't be legal either, for the same reason `void testMethod(String x) { String x = ""; }` doesn't compile. You can't re-declare a variable in the same scope with the same name.

You see this 'has hidden parameters and writes them out to the fields at the end' in the bytecode. Specifically, the last part:

```
15: aload_0
16: aload_1
17: putfield      #9
```

is bytecode-ese for `this.name = param1`. slot 0 is generally always used for the this ref, and slot 1 is here used for that parameter. The operation is 'write this value to that field' (that's what `putfield` does), and to do this job, the stack needs to be: [A] the receiver, and [B] the value to put there. Hence, `aload_0` (loads `this`) and then `aload_1` (loads `name` param).

That `name = name == null ? "a" : name` overwrites what the above bytecode ends up loading via `aload_1` is in this part:

```
4: aload_1
5: ifnonnull     13
8: ldc           #7                  // String a
10: goto          14
13: aload_1
14: astore_1
```

`aload_1` is still 'load param `name`', so, 4 loads it in, 5 does a nullcheck on this and consumes it (bytecode is stack based, so `aload_1` pushes the `name` value onto the stack. `ifnonnull` pops a value off the stack and hops to item 13 if the value wasn't null and just goes to the instruction if it was.

If it was null, the next instruction is `ldc` (which is short for 'load constant'), this pushes constant value `"a"` onto the stack. It then goes to 14.

If it wasn't null, we hop to 13: We `aload_1` again (we push param value `name` on the stack), and end up at 14 too, which now STORES this (`astore_1`).

SIDENOTE: bytecode wise this seems *very* inefficient (why `aload_1` and then `astore_1`? Why not skip past both the aload AND the astore with the jump statement?) - but bytecode isn't designed to be emitted as being efficient. Unlike e.g. C compilers `javac` intentionally does not optimize, it has no optimization layers (no `-O3` or similar command line switch the way e.g. `gcc` does), and must follow spec to the letter.

The reason is: That sort of optimization *is* done by java, but is done at runtime, by hotspot. Not by `javac`.

Comment: I already know the vast majority of this answer, and somehow I don't think it answers what I am asking for. I will re-read tomorrow.

Comment: @Eugene If you are familiar with all of this, then obviously the answer to your only actual question is 'yes'.

Comment: my question is more a rant, really. If you look at this code in a record `name = name == null ? "a" : name;` and have the mindset of pre-records, it makes no sense, imo. Because the way code is, it seems that it tries to re-assign `name` variable and that is not the case.

Comment: If you just want to rant you should probably mention that in your 'question'. Or probably skip past SO in the first place. SO questions and answers are intended to be for broader consumption: Yes, you asked it, but the point of SO is that others may at some point also ask it. Just because this is all trodden ground for _you_ doesn't matter. The only relevant part is: Does it answer the question. I interpreted the question as "Please explain the bytecode that is generated when writing compact constructors that modify record components". I think this answers the question thoroughly.

Comment: No no, you're 100% right. I thought there is something smarter or hidden here, not sure. Thx for your time

Comment: The bytecode just reflects the inefficiency of the original statement, `name = name == null ? "a" : name;` which assigns `name` to itself when non-`null`. You could simply write `if(name == null) name = "a";` instead. @Eugene it wouldn’t be different if, let’s say, the fields were pre-initialized with the constructor arguments but the constructor was allowed to modify it like a post-fix ignoring the final nature. In either case, you would change `name` if `name` doesn’t contain the correct value.

Comment: @Holger totally agree, this is what I thought is going on when I looked at it, cause `final` has no meaning for the bytecode itself. It would have been easier to grasp (at least for me) if that would have been the case. I still can't build a mental model of how to interpret `name = name == null ? "a" : name;` besides remembering that this will be a local copy :(

Comment: @Eugene but why? As said, it wouldn’t matter if `name` was just the field. So you don’t have to remember that `name` is the parameter. In contrast, why did you try to write `this.name` in the first place? That would only make sense if you already knew that `name` is the parameter.

Comment: @Holger you stopped the quote riight when it got interesting: "You can write it, The compiler knows what you mean, and will always error on it". My intent was to convey 'it is syntactically correct'. I'll edit.

Comment: I was always sure that you mean the right thing and it’s just a matter of phrasing. The new version is batter but it’s still that “this.field is wrong in any record constructor” should be either, “accessing this.field is wrong in a record’s compact canonical constructor” or “writing this.field is wrong in the compact canonical constructor or any other record constructor”.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I knew I was going to get in trouble by saying that. I am not a native english speaker and I honestly thought that it would have a far less offensive meaning. Lesson learned.